# Howto format php array values & insert them into database

Tags: php, arrays, csv, converters

This is my code where I read csv file (which I get from the bank), parsing it into array & insert it into database:

```
$csvFile = file('tecajnica.csv');
$keys = str_getcsv(array_shift($csvFile), ';');
foreach ($csvFile as $csvRecord) {
    // combine our $csvRecord with $keys array
    $csv[] = array_combine($keys, str_getcsv($csvRecord, ';'));
}

foreach( $csv as $row) {
$db2 = new PDO ("odbc:as400");
$sqlf93p = $db2->prepare("INSERT INTO..... VALUES (".$row['sifra'].",".$row['Kupovni2']." ......)
$sqlf93p->execute();
```

This is how my array looks like:

```
[0]=>
  array(10) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "67"
    ["drzava"]=>
    string(10) "Australija"
    ["sifra"]=>
    string(7) "036 AUD"
    ["VrijediZa"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Kupovni1"]=>
    string(8) "4,5207"
    ["Kupovni2"]=>
    string(8) "4,589597"
    }
[1]=>
  array(10) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["drzava"]=>
    string(5) "Ceska"
    ["sifra"]=>
    string(7) "203 CZK"
    ["VrijediZa"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Kupovni1"]=>
    string(8) "0,277098"
    ["Kupovni2"]=>
    string(8) "0,2821"
 }
```

* * * * * * * etc * * * * * *

So my questions are:

1) Howto convert `["sifra"]=> "203 CZK"` to `["sifra"]=> "203"` (I want only numeric value to appear before insert)?

2) Howto convert `["Kupovni2"]=> "0,2821"` to `["Kupovni2"]=> "0,282100"` (I want 6 decimal places before insert)?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) Just cast to integer. 2) Replace "," with "." and then use function ```numer_format```.

Comment: `$sqlf94p` is undefined. One line above you used `$sqlf93p`.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed $sqlf94p to $sqlf93p. My mistake..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option could be to replace all non digits using `\D+` with an empty string.

```
$digitsOnly = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', "203 CZK");
echo $digitsOnly; // 203
```

For appending the zeroes, you might use [str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
$parts = explode(',', '0,2821');
$str = implode(',', [$parts[0], str_pad($parts[1], 6, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT)]);
echo $str; // 0,282100
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/i9gkM)

Your code might look like:

```
foreach( $csv as $row) {
    $db2 = new PDO ("odbc:as400");
    $sifra = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $row['sifra']);
    $parts = explode(',', $row['Kupovni2']);
    $kupovni2 = implode(',', [$parts[0], str_pad($parts[1], 6, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT)]);
    $sqlf93p = $db2->prepare("INSERT INTO..... VALUES (". $sifra . "," . $kupovni2 ." ......);
    $sqlf93p->execute();
```

Comment: Many thanks to all of you. You save me from long googling and searching ;)
I've tried Rakesh Jakhar's and The fourth bird's solution and both of them solved my problem.

Now, I have just one more question.

When I get empty value from array, I'm getting ",000000" with implode/explode solution and "00000000" with simple str_pad.
How can I get first digit before comma (0,000000)?

Thanks.

Comment: You could check if the value is empty and then add `0,000000`

Answer (score 0):

1. To get number from a string you can do it this way

   ```
   $string = '203 CZK';
   echo (int) $string;
   ```

OR

```
$string = '203 CZK';
echo filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
```

2. To make string to length 8 you can use str_pad

   ```
   $string = '0,2821';
   echo str_pad($string, 8, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
   ```

Result :-

```
0,282100
```